# only png, gif, jpeg and pdf should be accepted

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

I know that this topic has been discussed many times before but I hope that I can be helped here. I want to use `mime_content_type` and only allow the types: `png`, `gif`, `jpeg` and `pdf`.

I have tried several other examples but it always takes the else Path even if the image is a png. Here is my code:

```
$imageMimeTypes = array(
                    'image/png',
                    'image/gif',
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'application/pdf');

                    
                
                $fileMimeType = mime_content_type($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);

                
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalFiles; $i++) {
                        
                            $fileMimeType = mime_content_type($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
                            $path = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
                            $name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'][$i];
                            
                            if(in_array($fileMimeType, $imageMimeTypes)) {
                               $mail->addattachment($path,$name);
                               echo $name . ' successfull <br>';
                             } else {
                               echo $name . ' is not a image or pdf <br>';
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you actually checked what `$fileMimeType` contains when you check your files that you expect to work?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what I would need to do to make this happen?

Comment: What exactly does `file your_file_here` show in terminal?

Comment: When I output $fileMimeType with echo nothing comes up at all

Comment: The return type for the method is `string|false`. [The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) says it emits a warning on failure so have you got error reporting enabled?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to php and don't know exactly what you mean :D

Comment: @allstar_141 You can learn about error reporting here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php . Can you try var_dump($fileMimeType); instead of echo ?

Comment: @TahirAli Then I get "string(4)"

Comment: The `4` is length of the string. What is the actual string? It should be after that.

Comment: @user3783243 I unfortunately made a mistake the correct answer is "image/png"

Comment: So it says `string(9) "image/png"`? Also you are var_dump in the `for` loop?

Comment: no it says string(13) "image/png". I don't know why and yes i'm in the loop

Comment: More importantly here, you should verify that this file you believe is not an `image/png` by using the [`file`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command. [`git bash`](https://git-scm.com/downloads) has this embedded for you to use if you're on `windows`. This is important because you're most likely incorrectly naming a `image/png` file as `.jpeg` - [the extension of a file means nothing](https://i.imgur.com/WReLFXR.png) (yes, I renamed a JPEG to a `.pdf` for PoC).

Comment: but i also accept .jpeg shouldn't it still work then? No matter what image I take even if I upload a pdf document it does not work

Comment: You haven't actually confirmed what it is, if it was taken via an iPhone with "live preview" it won't be a `png` nor a `jpeg`. Confirm it... its called `debugging`... Point is, its failing somewhere and you're assuming this file is not a `image/png`. `if(in_array())` would not `fail` if it is indeed outputting `image/png` anyway. Truthly, I cannot replicate this. [It works fine](https://3v4l.org/IJ4Y9).

Comment: Can you help me to include this in the code or what I need to look for so that I can test it myself? The png's I use are screenshots of windows taken with "Snagit 2020" so they are really png's

Comment: I cannot debug for you, you're not providing a minimalistic, reproducible environment. You're saying that the `mime_content_type` returns `image/png` and thus your code works as expected.  If it isn't returning any of the stated types in your white-listed array then you should debug what it is returning and if its failing, then [turn on error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and capture `E_WARNING`, or `E_ALL` for development sake, since the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) states it emits a warning on failure.

Comment: okay thanks I try

Comment: @Jaquarh i get the error message "mime_content_type(): Can only handle string or stream arguments". 
What does this mean?

Comment: I cannot debug for you, I have no idea. You call `mime_content_type` twice on `$_FILES`, one is most probably returning `NULL` which thus is causing the exception.

Comment: I have more or less found the problem. It was because I called mime_content_type 2 times like you said  @Jaquarh
Thanks to all!